# Second Query says, that resultset is closed

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have 2 classes. The Problem is, that i got a resultset is closed exception if i try to execute the second query. The second querys `rs.next` returns true. Can you tell me at which position i close the wrong resources? If i remove `this.queryResult.close()` and `this.statement.close()` from the releaseResources() method, the error is "The connection has been closed. Dont i create with every call a new instance of connection, preparedstatement and resultset?

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InterruptedException {
                DatabaseConnectionHelper con = new DatabaseConnectionHelper();
                ResultSet rs = con.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [winfiler].[dbo].[customer_data]");
                System.out.println(rs.next());
                while(rs.next()){
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
                }
                con.releaseResources();
                ResultSet rs3 = con.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [winfiler].[dbo].[customer_data]");
                System.out.println(rs3.next());
                while(rs3.next()){
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
                }
    }
```

Helperclass for the db connection:

```
public class DatabaseConnectionHelper {

    private Connection connection=null;
    private PreparedStatement statement=null;
    private ResultSet queryResult=null;

    public Connection connectToDatabase(){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=******;user=********;password=********");
            return connection;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            MessageHelper.createClassNotFoundExceptionMessage("Eine exception ist aufgetreten", "Classe konnte nicht gefunden werden (Verbindung zur Datenbank)", ex.getMessage());
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            MessageHelper.createSQLExceptionMessage("Eine exception ist aufgetreten", "Probleme beim der Datenabfrage - DatabaseConnectionHelper", ex.getMessage());
        }
            return null;
    }

    public ResultSet executeQuery(String query){
        try{
            statement = connectToDatabase().prepareStatement(query);
            queryResult = statement.executeQuery();


            return queryResult;
        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            MessageHelper.createSQLExceptionMessage("Eine exception ist aufgetreten", "Probleme beim der Datenabfrage - DatabaseConnectionHelper", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean releaseResources(){
        try {
            this.queryResult.close();
            this.statement.close();
            this.connection.close();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            MessageHelper.createSQLExceptionMessage("Eine exception ist aufgetreten", "Resourcen konnten nicht freigegeben werden - DatabaseConnectionHelper", ex.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `releaseResources()` called `connection.close()`.  So, it is no surprise that the connection is closed after calling this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual problem is that you call `rs.getString("name");` instead of `rs3.getString("name");` in your second loop.

Your `connectToDatabase()` creates a new connection. So this is not the problem as long as you do not use DBConnectionHelper concurrently.

BTW1: You should avoid the `System.out(rs.next());` as this has side effects and skips first row.
BTW2: your `releaseResources()` can be improved: you should ignore/seperately catch exceptions from RS and satement or at least close the connection itself in a finally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call con.releaseResources(), just before the second query, you're actually releasing the connection object.

Comment: no, the con.executeQuery() allocates a new one. (con is not a connection).